# Redirect to previous path on login - React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router

I am using react router v4 and trying to implement a functionality where no matter what route the user clicks on, he gets taken to the login page i.e. if he is not logged in already.

but after login he is redirected to the same page he was trying to access before login

I have managed to do that for 2 of the routes using the below code, but not sure if this is the best way to do this

```
<Route path="/dashboard" render={(props) => (
    auth ? 
    (<MainDash props={this.props} />) 
    : 
    (<Redirect to="/login"/>)
    )}
/>
<Route exact path="/customers" render={(props) => (
    auth ? 
    (<MainApp />) 
    : 
    (<Redirect to="/login"/>)
    )}
/>
<Route exact path="/staff" render={(props) => (
    auth ? 
    (<MainApp />)
    : 
    (<Redirect to="/login"/>)
    )}
/>
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
<Route path="/logout" component={Login} />
```

Now, although this is working correctly, I dont want to repeat the same code again and again for all the different routes. so is there a better way to do this?

Now, after logging out, it wasnt showing anything and I wanted it to show the login page. therefore I added the below lines too, so it would show the login page as soon as the user logs out.

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/logout" component={Login} />
```

But there's one more problem -> although after logout it does display the login component,(still showing route as '/logout') but it brings me back to login form (this time route is '/login' ) and from this route the login  takes me to the dashboard. Now, why is that happening?

Would appreciate some help on this as I am still learning about react router

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Following this [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) you can make a component `PrivateRoute` to wrap `Route` and use that whenever you need a route that requires auth.

This is the component code from the example.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? 
            (<Component {...props}/>) 
            : 
            (
              <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: '/login',
                    state: { from: props.location }
                }}
              />
            )
        )}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Previous answers are not detail enough.

Solution:

### Router

```
<BrowserRouter basename={BASE_NAME}>
  <Switch>
    {publicRouteList()}
    <Route exact key="login" path="/login" component={Login} />
    {getLoggedRouteList(state.logged)}
    <Redirect key="redirect-login" to="/login" />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

### getLoggedRouteList

```
const getLoggedRouteList = (logged) => {
  if (!logged) {
    return (
      <Route
        key="wait-login"
        render={props => {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { from: props.location },
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  const output = [];
  output.push(
    /* Here place route list that need logged */
  );
  return output;
}
```

### Login Component

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  login = async param => {
    const { location } = this.props;
    const { state } = location;

    /* Here place request login api */

    // go to state.from if set before
    if (state && state.from) {
      history.replace(state.from);
    }
    // else go to home
    else {
      history.replace('/');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use query strings to accomplish this.

Add dependency [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to your react app.

Whenever the user is trying to access a protected path, you have to redirect to the log-in screen if the user is not logged in yet. To do this you will do something like this.

```
history.push('/login');
```

But we can pass the previous as a query as follows. We can take the previous path using `useLocation` from `react-router`

```
 const lastLocation = useLocation();
 history.push(`/login?redirectTo=${lastLocation}`);
```

Now after successful login, we can get the query string that was passed in the previous path. We can set a default path if the previous path is `null`.

```
 const handleSuccessLogin = () => {
      const location = useLocation();
      const { redirectTo } = queryString.parse(location.search);
      history.push(redirectTo == null ? "/apps" : redirectTo);
 };
```

Inspired by https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-query-strings/

Comment: easy and best answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I ended up doing it:

```
<Switch>
  {loggedIn ? null : <Route path='/protectedPath' render={(props) => {
    const {pathname} = props.location
    // if the user tries to access a protected location, but is NOT logged in
    // remember the location the user was trying to access
    this.lastLocation = pathname
    // redirect to login page
    return <Redirect to='/loginPath' />
   }} />}
   <Route exact path='/loginPath' render={(props) => {
     return <Login {...props} lastLocation={this.lastLocation} />
   }} />
</Switch>
```

Then, inside my `Login`-Component I check if `lastLocation`-property is set to check if user should be redirected after login.

The only thing that bothers me with this solution, is that functional code is used inside the render method of the first route. But because it redirects immediatly, I hope this can be neglected.