# React-Router not updating URL on redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have an app using [react-router-v4](/questions/tagged/react-router-v4). I have a matching page which, unless you are logged in, you can't access. When a user is not logged in and tries to go to `/match` they get redirected to `/login`. My issue is that when the user is redirected to `/login` the URL stays as /match. This is causing issues elsewhere in my code. How can I get React-Router to update the URL when the user is redirected to `/login`? I am redirecting the page from my switch inside App.js. Here is an example of what my code looks like:

```
<Route
    path='/match'
    component= {
        () => {
            if (this.state.auth) return <HomePage />;
            else return <LoginPage />;
        }
    }
/>
```

**TL;DR**

How can I get the URL to change to `/login` if the user isn't logged in when trying to access `/match`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to previous path on login - React Router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906811/redirect-to-previous-path-on-login-react-router-v4)

Comment: @RagulParani Thanks, I have looked at the answer provided to that question and tried to implement it, however I am getting the error: 'Private Route is not defined'. I am using jsx, not tsx, so I tried taking out the const when adding the code to my file, which isn't working. Not sure how else to put that code into my file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have a little miss conception on how React Router works. In your example React Router works just as it should since you are just rendering components.

You should use React Router's `<Redirect />` -component for redirecting user to new url.

You could achieve your desired behaviour with this example code.

```
<Route
  path='/match'
  render={
    () => {
      if(this.state.auth) return <HomePage />
      return <Redirect to="/login" />
    }
  }
/>
<Route match="login" component={Login} />
```

You can also achieve same kind of behaviour inside component programmatically with using React Router's provided prop `props.history.push('/login')` inside your component.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a separate route for `/login`, and use the [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) component on your `/match` route if the user is not logged in.

```
<Route
  path='/match'
  render={
    () => {
      if (this.state.auth) return <HomePage />;
      else return <Redirect to='/login'/>;
    }
  }
/>
<Route
  path='/login'
  render={LoginPage}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic for redirect should be part of component itself, not routes configuration. To make it reusable create [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) with redirect logic, and then just wrap paths that should be protected in routes config.